# Why delegate protocol method is not recognized in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I looked at lots of threads about delegation but couldn't find why this isn't working
I have UINavigationController in storyboard in Xcode  5 and here is how the delegate is assigned:
in MasterViewController I have:

```
//
// MasterViewController.h
//
@protocol MyViewDelegate
@required
- (void) getBackContacts:(NSArray *)c andEmails:(NSArray *)e;
@end

@interface ListContactsViewController : UITableViewController <MyViewDelegate> {

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* myString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ABContact* currentML;

@end


//
// MasterViewController.m
//

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    DetailtViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc.currentML = _currentML;
    vc.contacts = _contacts;
    vc.emails = _emails;
}

- (void) getBackContacts:(NSArray *)c andEmails:(NSArray *)e
{
    _contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:c];
    _emails   = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:e];
}
```

for DetailViewController I have:

```
//
// DetailViewController.h
//
@protocol MyViewDelegate;

@interface SelectContactViewController : UITableViewController {
    id< MyViewDelegate > delegate;

}
-(IBAction) save;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id< MyViewDelegate > delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ABContact* currentML;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* contacts;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* emails;


//
// DetailViewController.m
//

- (IBAction) save
{
    // *** this line compiles with error
    [delegate getBackContacts:_contacts andEmails:_emails];
}
```

When I compile compiler says:

**No known instance method for selector 'getBackContacts:andEmails:'**

Comment: Well how do you expect the compiler to know which methods the protocol declares, if it doesn't see the complete definition of the protocol?

Comment: In other words `#import "MasterViewController.h"` in `DetailViewController.m`.

Comment: OH! You don't how many hours I was searching for a problem in delegate declaration! Thanks man!

Comment: There is rarely a reason to use forward declaration for a protocol

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by forward declaration?